# How do I scrape all the text in the //div[@class='body'] in this website?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

```
import scrapy


class ActScraper1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'act_scraper_1'
    allowed_domains = ['sso.agc.gov.sg']
    start_urls = ['https://sso.agc.gov.sg/Act/AA2004']

def parse(self, response):

    info = response.xpath("//div[@class='body']//text()").getall()
    yield {
        'info': info
    }
```

So my code above does part of the job as it only scrapes the first table out of the 8 tables in the div[@class='body'] tag

[image]

How do I get my scraper to scrape all the text in all the tables? Thanks!

Comment: Try to add '/table' to your xpath. I think getall() should then be a list of all the matching nodes, which would be all tables

Comment: Tried that! Apparently still gives the same result. Not sure if it's because this webpage used lazy loading

Comment: This indeed could be a point. You can disable Javascript in the browser developer tools and reload the page. Then you see, what your normal Scrapy spider sees. I have not digged into scraping JS content yet, but I think a prominent approach is using Scrapy with Splash

Comment: Yup! Disabling JS does give me the text that my spider scraped. Let me look into Splash! Thanks for the recommendation

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

disable Javascript in the browser and reload the page. Then you see the valid newest xpath (you can use 'Quick Javascipt Switcher' on your chrome browser to disable js)